# differential geometry - center of curvature - intersection of normals

Tags: differential-geometry

I am watching [this](https://youtu.be/_mvjOoTieTk) introduction to differential geometry, and at [this point](https://youtu.be/_mvjOoTieTk?t=1629) (27:09) he explains the evolute. However, I cannot see, how it is possible that the normals to the tangents of two adjecent points have any intersection in the limit that one point goes to the other, since if the curve is smooth, they have to become parallel and thus meet at infinity. What am i missing?

Comment: Think of a circle. Every normal to a tangent is basically a diameter. And every two diameters intersect at the center which is not going anywhere, much less to infinity. How so?

Comment: The limit of the intersection points of nearby lines is *not* the intersection of the limiting lines (which, of course, become a single line).